# Adding pecan flavor to brown ale

Tags: nuts

I have a extract-based brown ale that needs about another 1-2 weeks in primary before I bottle it. I'd like to add some pecan flavor.

Based on other things i've read (including [Hazelnut Brown Ale - What extract?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10365/hazelnut-brown-ale-what-extract)), I'm thinking about doing this:

1. Chop/smash and roast some quantity of pecans (maybe 1lb?)
2. Cover them in vodka to extract the flavor
3. Let that sit for the next 1-2 weeks
4. Add a small amount of the extract when bottling

Does this seem like a reasonable plan? Any thoughts on quantity of pecans and extract? I want to get some of the flavor without overpowering the brown ale (which look like it might hit 1.020 final gravity).

I also see (on the web):

- [directions for roasting pecans](https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/threads/pecan-pale-ale.81224/#post-861259); [similar directions](https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/threads/pecan-scottish-80.49707/)
- [a recipe for Pecan Porter](https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/homebrew-recipe/512-brewing-co-pecan-porter/) that calls for 12-16 oz ground pecans in the mash (too late for doing that, though that suggests a quantity of pecans)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, that seems like a solid plan.  A pound of pecans seems reasonable enough and if you end up with excess extract you can always save it for a later batch or anything else that could use some pecan flavor.

In terms of determining an appropriate amount to add to your beer, the best method is probably to measure out small quantities and try small mixes until you find a ratio that fits the level of flavor you want.  If you have a beer that's similar to the one you're making on hand you can use that as a base beer, or you can take a sample of the beer you'll actually be adding it to and try it that way.  Using a small syringe to measure out 1/2/3 mL of extract at a time and mixing that with static amounts of beer is probably the most accurate method in terms of being able to scale it up to the full batch size.  But as long as you have some repeatable way of measuring small amounts of the extract you can then do the math to figure out how much you need to add to the whole batch to achieve the effect you're looking for.

It might be a little tedious but can eliminate a lot of the guess-work, especially if it's easy enough for you to make a lot of extract.  Especially since someone else's extract might not have the same strength/quality of flavor as yours and the amount they like might not be the same amount you'll like.

Answer (score 3):

Nuts are kinda hard to get flavor and aroma to infuse into the beer.

You can get much more character from nuts if they are blended into a slurry then added late fermentation.

Use a blender with boiling hot water (to pastureize). Use enough water so the slurry pours easily. Let cool to fermentation temp so you don't kill yeast when adding to fermentor.